# Spring data neo4j - GraphProperty on method

Tags: scala, spring-data-neo4j

I was looking at the definition of `GraphProperty` annotation for `spring-data-neo4j` and it looks something like this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface GraphProperty {
```

now, I wanted to store in database value of the computed property, so I made something like:

```
@GraphProperty
def fooProperty: String = "aaa"
```

but nothing got saved.

If you can't use `GraphProperty` annotation on no-argument functions, why it has `target` set to method? Or am I doing something wrong?